Why Does Visual Studio IntelliSense Incorrectly Suggest Binding to Page ViewModel Instead of ItemSource in TabControl?
I'm working on a WPF application where I have a TabControl bound to a collection of LogFile objects. Here's a simplified version of my XAML:
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding LogFiles}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding LoggerName}" Width="100" Height="20" FontSize="14"
                   Background="#40FFFFFF" Foreground="White" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LogContent}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>

And my LogFile class looks like this:
public class LogFile
{
    public string LoggerName { get; set; }
    public string LogContent { get; set; }
}

At runtime, everything works as expected—LogContent is correctly displayed in the TextBox. However, Visual Studio's IntelliSense and XAML editor show a warning that the Binding for LogContent is targeting the LogContent property of the page's ViewModel instead of the LogFile class. Despite the warning, the application runs without any issues.
Why is Visual Studio showing this misleading warning, and how can I resolve or suppress it?
